flutter in-app purchase error: getskudetails() failed for queryproductdetailsasync. response code: 2
I'm trying to set up in_app_purchase for both play and app store, app store works well!
Here is the relevant part:
final InAppPurchase inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
await inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
final ProductDetailsResponse response =
  await inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails({productId});

For play store I just tried everything possible and as far as I'm concerned all the steps have been carried out completely including store configuration and publishing to internal/closed testing track etc (app signed with own keystore) but I still get this when trying to retrieve a product:
getskudetails() failed for queryproductdetailsasync. response code: 2
All in all I just think it would work as-is, maybe there is some gotcha I don't understand. I just have no idea how to proceed from here, any suggestions appreciated thanks!
